# Filling RichTextbox with many lines hangs UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am filling Richtextbox with adding lines from another thread that extract links from web. when the web urls links increase and go more than 9000 it hangs the UI and take long time don't know why ! , using button click event to fire this method ( thread )

Using AppendText(Environment.NewLine) method to fill the richtextbox

Here is the snippet code of my work :

```
if (URLLMemoRichTxt.Lines.Length == 0)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("You have to get some links first");
                return;
            }


            var thd = new Thread(() =>
            {

                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {


                    if (URLLMemoRichTxt.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        URLLMemoRichTxt.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                        {

                            foreach (string line in URLLMemoRichTxt.Lines)
                            {
                                if (!GetEmailsListArraylist.Contains(line) && line.Trim() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    if (LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.InvokeRequired)
                                    {
                                        LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                                        {

                                            GetEmailsListArraylist.Add(line);
                                        //   LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Text += line + "\n";
                                        LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);

                                            LinksToGetEmailsLabel.Text = LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Lines.Length.ToString();

                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {


                                        GetEmailsListArraylist.Add(line);
                                    //   LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Text += line + "\n";
                                    LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);

                                        LinksToGetEmailsLabel.Text = LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Lines.Length.ToString();

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (string line in URLLMemoRichTxt.Lines)
                        {
                            if (!GetEmailsListArraylist.Contains(line) && line.Trim() != string.Empty)
                            {
                                GetEmailsListArraylist.Add(line);
                                //   LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Text += line + "\n";
                                LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);

                                LinksToGetEmailsLabel.Text = LinksToGetEmailsRichTxt.Lines.Length.ToString();


                            }
                        }
                        if (MainTabcontrol.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            MainTabcontrol.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                            {
                                MainTabcontrol.SelectedTabPageIndex = 1;

                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MainTabcontrol.SelectedTabPageIndex = 1;

                        }
                    }




                }
                else
                {





                }
                if (MainTabcontrol.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    MainTabcontrol.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                    {
                        MainTabcontrol.SelectedTabPageIndex = 1;

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    MainTabcontrol.SelectedTabPageIndex = 1;


                }

            });
            thd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
            thd.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

> using button click event to fire this method ( thread )

Here is your code, boiled down:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        if (URLLMemoRichTxt.InvokeRequired)
        {
            URLLMemoRichTxt.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                // .. do some "work" in here ...
                Thread.Sleep(9000);
            });
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

Let's analyze what's happening here:

1. User clicks the button.
2. Running in the UI thread, the Click event creates a New Thread and starts it.
3. Inside that new thread, immediately ask if we are running in a different thread than the one that owns the RichTextBox with `InvokeRequired` (the answer is, of course, yes!).
4. Tell the application to run some code on the thread that owns the RichTextBox with `Invoke()`.
5. Running in the UI thread **again**, do the actual "work".

End Result?

- All your "work" is run in the main UI thread as if no threading ever occurred.
- Why create a thread and then tell it to run its work back on the UI thread?

How should it be done correctly?

Here's a slightly more robust version of the boiled down code, with only the part that updates the UI within the `Invoke()` block:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            // do some "work" in our new thread
            for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // the "work"

                // when you need to UPDATE THE UI, now is the time for Invoke()
                // note that only the part that is updating the UI is within this block
                // the rest of the code/loop is still running in the new thread
                URLLMemoRichTxt.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    URLLMemoRichTxt.AppendText("Line " + i.ToString() + "\r\n");
                });

                // ... possibly more work in the new thread ...

            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

With this approach, the UI will remain responsive while the `for` loop runs and the work is done.  Additionally, the RichTextBox will happily update with the new entries without blocking.